# Scala operator overloading with multiple parameters

Tags: scala, syntax, operator-overloading, dsl

**In short:** I try to write something like `A <N B` for a DSL in Scala, for an integer N and A,B of Type T. Is there a nice possibility to do so?

**Longer:** I try to write a DSL for [TGrep2](http://tedlab.mit.edu/~dr/Tgrep2/tgrep2.pdf) in Scala. I'm currently interested to write

```
A <N B          B is the Nth child of A (the rst child is <1).
```

in a nice way and as close as possible to the original definition in Scala. Is there a way to overload the `<` Operator that it can take a N and a B as a argument.

**What I tried:** I tried two different possibilities which did not make me very happy:

```
scala> val N = 10
N: Int = 10

scala> case class T(n:String) {def <(i:Int,j:T) = println("huray!")}
defined class T

scala> T("foo").<(N,T("bar"))
huray!
```

and

```
scala> case class T(n:String) {def <(i:Int) = new {def apply(j:T) = println("huray!")}}
defined class T

scala> (T("foo")<N)(T("bar"))
warning: there were 1 feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
huray!
```

Comment: Id suggest you use something like `nth` instead of the `<` symbol which makes the semantics clear. `A nth N is B` would make a lot of sense to me at least.

Comment: Scala's "operator" syntax sugar allows `foo.bar(baz)` to become `foo bar baz`, but it doesn't apply to functions with multiple arguments. You'll want to re-think your DSL so that your statement is more like `foo.bar(baz).bang(biff)` (`A nth N is B`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Id suggest you use something like `nth` instead of the `<` symbol which makes the semantics clear. `A nth N is B` would make a lot of sense to me at least. It would translate to something like

```
case class T (label:String){
  def is(j:T) = {
label equals j.label
  }
}

case class J(i:List[T]){
  def nth(index:Int) :T = {
    i(index)
  }
}
```

You can easily do:

```
val t  = T("Mice")
val t1 = T("Rats")
val j  = J(List(t1,t))

j nth 1 is t //res = true
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `apply` doesn't work as a postfix operator, so you can't write it without the parantheses, you could write this:

```
  case class T(n: String) {
    def <(in: (Int, T)) = {
      in match {
        case (i, t) =>
          println(s"${t.n} is the ${i} child of ${n}")

      }
    }
  }

  implicit class Param(lower: Int) {
    def apply(t: T) = (lower, t)
  }
```

but then,

```
T("foo") < 10 T("bar")
```

would still fail, but you could work it out with:

```
T("foo") < 10 (T("bar"))
```

there isn't a good way of doing what you want without adding parenthesis somewhere.

I think that you might want to go for a [combinational parser](http://debasishg.blogspot.com.br/2008/04/external-dsls-made-easy-with-scala.html) instead if  you really want to stick with this syntax. Or as @korefn proposed, you break the compatibility and do it with new operators.